# Is it safe to delete the Snapshots folders from QTP tests?

Tags: qtp

In a given test's folder, there is the following structure:

Action0

->Snapshots

->->Lots of *.pngs, *.htmls, etc.

.

.

.

ActionN

What are the snapshots used for? From what I've seen at http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/46983, they're used for the Active Screen view, which we don't use.

What might happen if I delete all of the snapshots and turn off their capture by going to Tools->Options->Active Screen->Set to None?

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you point to is correct, the snapshots are used only for active screen. You can delete them safely and maintain all of QTP's functionality that doesn't relate to active screens.

You can prevent QTP from saving these files in the first place by setting the active screen level to **none**, or by unchecking the `Save Active Screen files` in the **Save Test** dialog.

In either case QTP seems to create the **Snapshots** folder but it is empty. In the second case you get the following (self explanatory message).

[image: Message when not saving active screen files]